# Adding Fields To Devise Sign Up Using Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

To start off, I'm new to rails, so I'm still getting the hang of things.

I'm attempting to add two fields to the Devise sign up page, a first name field and a last name field. I've gone ahead and changed the view and the controller in order to attempt this. They look like this:

Controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_action :configure_devise_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_devise_permitted_parameters
    registration_params = [:firstName, :lastName, :email, :password, :password_confirmation]

    if params[:action] == 'update'
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { 
        |u| u.permit(registration_params << :current_password)
    }
    elsif params[:action] == 'create'
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { 
        |u| u.permit(registration_params) 
      }
    end
  end
end
```

View:

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :firstName %><br />
  <%= f.fName_field :firstName %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :lastName %><br />
  <%= f.lName_field :lastName %></div>

  <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
<% end %>
<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

However, I get this error when I go to view the page:

```
undefined method `fName_field' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x00000003c89940>
```

Where must I define those methods? or are they automatically defined somewhere else?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With "f.something" you can just define the type of the field in the form. Try something like

```
<%= f.text_field :lastName %>
```

This should work.

You can read about the available types of fields here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for

Comment: This fixed my issue. I did not realize there were predefined fields for forms. Thank you very much sir.

Comment: Glad that i could help you!

Answer (score 1):

create a migration like this to add first name and last name to users table:-

```
class AddFirstnameAndLastnameToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
   add_column :users, :firstName, :string
   add_column :users, :lastName, :string
  end
end
```

And add this to your view :-

```
     <div><%= f.label :firstName %><br />
          <%= f.text_field :firstName%></div>
     <div><%= f.label :lastName %><br />
          <%= f.text_field :lastName %></div>
```

You can not do f. to column of the table, you do it on the type of the field.

Answer (score 0):

```
undefined method `fName_field'
```

This means you don't have the fName column in your database

---

If you have access to your DB, you'll see that Devise produces a table with a bunch of columns inside. By default, these columns only include email & password for the user. To add more, you first need to add the column to the database & then you should be able to do what you're doing with it.

There's a good [railscast on devise](http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise) you can see how to do this

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a very common mistake done by a rookie while creating a registration form on the very first time because the devise puts all of the fields like ***f.email_field,f.password_field*** etc but these all are valid controls, so the developer gets confuse to type an attribute with **_field**
The '**fname_field**' you used to define your first name is not acceptable as the form controls.

Please verify all of the controls which can be used [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#other-helpers-of-interest)

and as per the current scenario, you should go for **f.text_field**